# Blazor - Two-way binding on a Collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, frontend, blazor

**Is it possible to Two-way bind an collection in Blazor child component?**

**TLDR**; A property of type list in an object is set to `null` when the `ValueChanged` `EventCallBack` handler is executed, and this throws `NullReferenceException`s because its set to `null` in the pages.

I have the following example:

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public List<string> NickNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
```

The main page: `Index.razor`

```cs
<h1>@Mario.FullName - @string.join('-', Mario.NickNames)</h1>
<NicknamesListComponent @bind-Nicknames="Mario.NickNames" />

@code{
    public Person Mario { get; set; } = 
        new Person() { FullName = "Mario", NickNames = new List<string> {"Super", "Mama" , "Mia"} }

}
```

The child component: `NicknamesListComponent.razor`

```cs
<ul>
    @for(int i = 0; i < Nicknames.Count; i++)
    {
      @var index = i;
      <li>
         @Nicknames[index]
         <a @onclick="() => RemoveNickname(index)">Remove</a>
      </li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Nicknames { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<string>> NicknamesChanged { get; set; }

    public async Task RemoveNickname(int index)
    {
        Nicknames.RemoveAt(index);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // When executing NicknamesChanged. the User.Nicknames property is completly cleared and 
        // set to NULL... this throws exceptions everywhere in the index.blazor
        await NicknamesChanged.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

If I remove the `NicknamesChanged`, then the list with the **Delete** button works... but this time the parent is not notified of changes and the nicknames stay the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null is because you are calling `NicknamesChanged.InvokeAsync()` with void.

For two way binding to work:

```
    await NicknamesChanged.InvokeAsync(Nicknames);
```

Side note: I am assuming it is a typo but `string.Join(...)` not `string.join(...)`

If you fix those two issues your code will work. However...

A better way by avoiding the for loop issue:

```
<ul>
    @foreach(var nickname in Nicknames)
    {
      <li @key=nickname>
         @nickname
         <a @onclick="() => RemoveNickname(nickname)">Remove</a>
      </li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Nicknames { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<string>> NicknamesChanged { get; set; }

    public async Task RemoveNickname(string nickname)
    {
        Nicknames.Remove(nickname);
        await NicknamesChanged.InvokeAsync(Nicknames);
    }
}
```

The `@key` should be used as you could remove the wrong nickname.

[Repl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QFkzkBbJ03yvGw9a06)

Comment: Sweet ! Yup the `await NicknamesChanged.InvokeAsync(Nicknames)` did the trick! Not sure why Microsoft didnt note that in the docs, Thanks!

Reason for the RemoveAt() instead of the Remove() was purely performanse wise, i agree that this is cleaner code.
+1

Answer (score 1):

you have to return the NickNames on NicknamesChanged, and the recommendation is don't change the NickNames Parameter. use local variable instead.

the updated code is:

```
<ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Nicknames.Count; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        <li>
            @Nicknames[index]
            <a @onclick="() => RemoveNickname(index)">Remove</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Nicknames { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<string>> NicknamesChanged { get; set; }

    public async Task RemoveNickname(int index)
    {
        Nicknames.RemoveAt(index);

        await NicknamesChanged.InvokeAsync(Nicknames);
    }
}
```